# Not getting Custom Toolbar Title

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I tried various solution to get toolbar title but none of them worked. like using and others. What went wrong with my code. can you advice. I m getting menu and their options but Title of toolbar no luck.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello");
```

Below is my style.xml code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My mainactivity code:

```
package jss.customtoolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello");

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

menu.xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miCompose"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Compose"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProfile"
        android:title="Profile" />
</menu>
```

Toolbar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:title="Hello">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">




        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

and activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="jss.customtoolbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/tool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set title to toolbar for reference  no need to get toolbar of support.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Hello");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Toolbar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:title="Hello">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="jss.customtoolbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/tool"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: still same result without title.

Comment: Finally worked after removing redundant relativelayout.